# edit comments capability for authors

Tags: comments, author

I am using wp site where registered users have authors roles.

I want authors to have permissions to **edit their own comments**. Now only admin user have capability to edit comments and even editors do not have this capability.

I tried plugins like Role Scoper or Members but they don't have this capabilities

Comment: If you are looking for a plugin this is going to be off-topic. Are you talking about edit capability on the front end or the back end, or both?

Comment: plugin is good but i can use functions.php as well
in back end is more important (both also sounds great)

Answer (score 1):

The role needs "edit_post" capability to edit comments (the reason beeing that comments are posts for wordpress)
--> do your authors have "edit_post" capability?
this enables the role to edit posts also, which might not be desired.

Wordpress capabilites are weird.
There exists a meta capability 'edit_comment', but its not very intuitive. As far as I understand it currently, you can not directly assign it to a user (you can assign "edit_comment" capability, but it seems to be treated as custom created capability and therefore ignored..

I tried to let my subscribers edit their own comments, but

```
$subscriber= get_role('subscriber'); 
$subscriber->add_cap('edit_comment');
```

seems to have no effect for me, you can try it for authors but it probably won't do the trick.
)

read this:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/edit-comment-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-comment-editing/
and then add a little trick to get more editing frame time:

```
    add_filter( 'sce_comment_time', 'edit_sce_comment_time' );
function edit_sce_comment_time( $time_in_minutes ) {
    return 10; // Here you change the time period after that, the user is not able to edit their comment.
}
```